# How to remove a part of text using replaceAll

Tags: java, replaceall

There is a `String text`
`System.out.println(text);` looks like this

```
So the traveller sat down by the side of that old man,
face to face with the serene sunset; 
and all his friends came softly back and stood around him.
```

---

Another `String subText`

`System.out.println(subText);` is simply a part of the above string and looks like this

```
So the traveller sat down by the side of that old man,
face to face with the serene sunset;
```

---

I need to get rid of this `subText` part `text = text.replaceAll(subtext, "");` but this does not do anything with the text?

Comment: Beware: String.replaceAll in Java uses regular expressions.

Comment: It works for me. (Make sure you have the exact thing in subtext.)

Comment: maybe check that the subtext is in the string before removing it. might be a typo in your subtext. if( text.contains(subtext)){ do stuff } else{ print error}

Comment: Your basic code looks fine. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem. You also may way to start with removing a smaller text string first to make sure the code works and you don't have a typo anywhere. Then try it with a larger string because unless you have an exact match nothing will be replaced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case it does not matter, but you really should use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`:

```
text = text.replace(subtext, "");
```

The `replaceAll` method uses regular expressions, and some characters have special meaning.

In this particular case you won't see any difference because there must be something subtly different in  `subtext`, so it cannot be found in `text`. Perhaps there's extra white space or the line break character is encoded differently. It's very hard to see differences in white space looking at output produced by `System.out.println`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not working is because 'replaceAll()` expects the search term to be a *regular expression*.

You should use `replace()`, which use searches for plain text and incidentally still replaces all occurrences, instead:

```
text = text.replace(subtext, "");
```

As to why it didn't work with `replaceAll()`, who knows. To diagnose, you could see if in fact it's in your text as follows:

```
System.out.println(text.contains(subtext));
```

Comment: Doesn't multiline affect only the behavior of `^` and `$`?

Comment: @joni yeah. Seemed plausible at the time, but I've retracted that and put in something useful instead